# Does partition by / order by imply ordering in a query?

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-order-by

I see no difference in:

```
select
  ID,
  TYPE,
  XTIME,
  first_value(XTIME) over (partition by TYPE order by XTIME)
from SERIES;
```

and:

```
select
  ID,
  TYPE,
  XTIME,
  first_value(XTIME) over (partition by TYPE order by XTIME)
from SERIES
order by TYPE, XTIME;
```

Does partition by / order by imply ordering in a query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it does not.

The result set from a query is ordered only when it has an explicit `order by` clause.  Otherwise the result set is in an *arbitrary* order.  Often, the underlying algorithms used for running the query determine the ordering of the result set.

*You can only depend on the final ordering when you have an `order by` clause for the outermost `select`.*  That the result sets are in the same order is simply a coincidence.

I am curious why you don't simply use this?

```
min(xtime) over (partition by type)
```

Comment: Does that mean DB perform 2 sorting, one for `PARTITION BY` + `ORDER BY` of analytical function and another for `ORDER BY` of select (in that order)?

Comment: @gavenkoa . . . Probably not.  Oracle has a good optimizer so it would probably catch this.  In fact, if you have an index on `(type, xtime)`, Oracle might use the index and do no additional sorting at all.

Comment: @gavenkoa it might optimise the two identical sorts, it might not, depending on the query. The point is that you should not rely on an internal optimisation to get the specific order you need. `GROUP BY` used to return results in the order of the grouping keys until Oracle changed the internal implementation in 10g, catching a lot of people out.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between the two queries is that the second one would be ordered ascending by `TYPE` and then `XTIME`, while the first one would, in theory, have random ordering.

The `PARTITION BY` and `ORDER BY` clause used in the call to `FIRST_VALUE` have an effect on that particular analytic function, but do *not* by themselves affect the final order of the result set.

In general, if you want to order a result set in SQL, you need to use an `ORDER BY` clause.  If both your queries *happen* to have the same ordering right now, it is only by chance, and is not guaranteed.  How might this happen?  Well, if Oracle is iterating the clustered index of your table, and that ordering happens to coincide with `ORDER BY TYPE, XTIME`, then you would see this order even *without* using `ORDER BY`.

Comment: OK, so what I see in first query is implementation specific and is not  guarantied?

Comment: Gordon figured out what you are asking here.  If the two results set happened to be in the same order, it is only by chance.  There is no guarantee that this would always be the case.